# Single line query to group entries with duplicates

Tags: sql

I currently have a table with two attributes, *users* and *hits*.

`users` column has duplicates. `hits` attribute is either a Y or a N.

I want to perform a select query on this table to get users, hits grouped by the users. Such that **if a user has any entry** where hits=Y then the user's hit attribute should be set to Y.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Your hits column is boolean type or text?

Comment: And figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` statement:

```sql
SELECT 
    User, 
    CASE MAX(CASE Hits WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
    END AS Hits
FROM USR
GROUP BY User
```

Comment: Apologies, I just edited the question. Would this work if the Hits column is Y/N instead of 1s or 0s?

Comment: I edited the answer according to the new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your `hits` column is `boolean` type, use `bool_or` aggregate function for Postgresql

```sql
select 
user,
bool_or(hits)
from usr
Group by user
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an aggregation query:

```
select user, max(hits)
from t
group by user;
```